# How to set default value for entity reference field in hook_form_alter

Tags: 8, entities

following snippet doesn't   set the default value.

```
 $form['field_image']['#default_value']='default';
```

I Have content type called image and I'm trying to set the default value for a reference to it in another content type.  The above code doesn't work.  Printing out the form variable doesn't make it seem like an easy task.

Comment: Sadly in D8 the method for doing this depends on the widget being used in the form. The answer $form['field_myfield']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#default_value'] = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(2); only works if the widget is an autocomplete. If the widget is a select list, then you would need to use: $form['field_myfield']['widget']['#default_value'] = 2;

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to first check the structure of your form. Mine worked with the following:

```
$form['field_image']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#default_value'] = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(2);
```

Cheers!

Comment: How to check structure of the form :) ?

Comment: You can either use a `devel` module's function (`dsm()` or `dpm()`) or an IDE with a debugger. The debugger's breakpoint or the devel functions can be placed inside your own implementation of `hook_form_alter()` or directly inside the `drupal_prepare_form()` function.

Comment: Hmm.  Great for D7,  it's a protected object in D8 and doesn't seem to kint() to that level.  (A debugger might work).  Trying to find a workable way to look at $form in D8,  right now.
P.S.  apologies that I may have thought this was a D8 thread ...

Comment: UPDATE:  you can $var=$form_state['variable'] then kint($var).

Comment: It's a D8 thread, my bad, thought it was D7.

Comment: UPDATE:  you can't always touch $form_state in D8 but you can see $form,  and that's where you'll want to make changes AFAICT.  Display widget structure appears to vary widely,  alas.

Comment: I needed to use ['#value'] rather than ['#default_value']...

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with the above on 8.6.1 when using the *Entity browser widget* - looking at the form edit values I found that this worked for me:

```
      $form['field_business_partner']['widget']['target_id']['#default_value'] = 'node:18';
```

Simple string.  Note it didn't display the requisite node in the field but as this was being programmatically set it didn't matter in my use case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set three things, 
1 - node default value,
2 - Entity browser default value , And 
3 - Item , Which will show in edit form, Without Assigned the items it's not displayed in entity browser, While in backed it is set when we check by kint() var,
demo code in my case:

```
    $form['field_related_stories']['widget']['target_id']['#default_value'] = "node:25507";
    $form['field_related_stories']['widget']['entity_browser']['#default_value'] = Node::load(25507);
    $form['field_related_stories']['widget']['current']['items'] = array();
```

Comment: None of these show the default value _selected_ in the entity browser...any idea how to make that happen?