# Pre-populate an entity reference field (media image) when creating a node

Tags: 8, nodes

I am trying to open a node creation form (for example, `/node/add/article`) and to have an Entity Reference field pre-populated.

My field (`field_image`) is an **Entity Reference** to a **Media** of type **Image** and the form uses the **Media Library widget**.

I essentially tried doing that by implementing `hook_form_alter` in a custom module but nothing that I have tried worked. I saw solutions like [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/203562/39892). It works with other field types that I have tried. For example:

```
// Pre-populate Entity Reference field to taxonomy term

$term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load(13);
$form['field_category']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#default_value'] = $term;
```

The above works just fine. But the below doesn't.

```
// Pre-populate Entity Reference field to Media Image

$media = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('media')->load(38);
$form['field_image']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#default_value'] = $media;
```

I also tried by providing just the media id instead of the entity but it didn't work.

I have tried the [Prepopulate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate) too but couldn't get it to work either although it works with all other field types that I have tried.

Anyone knows if this is feasible and how?

*Edit: I should perhaps mention that I am not looking for a solution on how to set a default value for that field. The referenced entity must be set dynamically*

For reference, here is my complete code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function siteconfig_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'node_article_form') {

    // This works
    $term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load(13);
    $form['field_category']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#default_value'] = $term;

    // This doesn't work
    $media = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('media')->load(38);
    $form['field_image']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#default_value'] = $media;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's much easier to prepopulate field values on entity level rather than on form level, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259275/create-any-number-of-paragraph-fields-in-a-multiple-value-field-on-node-create-f

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll give this a try then. That doesn't explain why I am able to do it with any other field than a media field though. I suspect the issue is the widget but I might be wrong...

Comment: @4k4 Indeed, that worked like a charm! If you would like to turn this into an answer, please do and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to prepopulate field values on entity level rather than on form level:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create() for 'node'.
 */
function mymodule_node_create(\Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {

  if ($node->getType() == 'my_content_type') {
    $media = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('media')->load(38);
    $node->field_image[] = $media;
  }

}
```